# Beginner Java - using substring() to make a long string into seperate lines

Tags: java

We are suppose to write a calendar for a project.  I'm using an array to keep track of how many days in a month there are and get a long list of numbers equal to the value of that array index.  I then populate a String using a loop until that loop is equal to the value of that index.

The string is loaded into a textshape, which was given by our professor.  I want to display each text line that is generated by substring() into one separate line.  I tried to start at a higher index (30, 59) but it returns an error b/c my initial string isn't long enough.

So what i want to do is make that long list of numbers into separate lines.  A classmate of mine said to use substring. It does work, generally but will only give me the first line.

this is the method to generate my string.

```
    public String toString() {

    monthPlusOne = month + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < monthsArray[monthPlusOne]; i++) {
        String temp;
        //temp = "" + i;
        subLine = subLine + (i+1) + " ";

        }
    totalLine = subLine;


    String output = monthText + " " + year + " \n "
            + "Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa\n" + totalLine;

    return output;
}
```

it feeds into this this method which origanlly had the calender in just number form with manual "\n" inserted into it.  The string would split when it found those "\n"

```
public static void displayCalendar() {
    String s = calendar.toString().substring(30);

    // extract all of the lines in s
    // split s on \n
    String[] lines = s.split("\n");
    int index = 0;
    for (String line : lines) {
        t[index].setText(line);
        index++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi kitchen_duty ... are you trying to get substrings of a single string for example if you have string like "first second third" do you want three string "first", "second", "third" .... is that what you want ... I read your question but couldnt understand it

Comment: I know you're a beginner, but this code is almost unintelligible. mind cleaning it up a bit? to me, you're making this a lot harder than it needs to be. also, look into String's [split](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method.

Comment: I would suggest not using `substring` here. This can be designed cleaner without it.

Comment: I agree, a poster below this has suggested I use an if statement to inject "\n" into my code when i%7== 0.  It got me at least part way to the process now i just need to get the start date correct and clean it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of all those substring() and split() calls and add

```
if((i + 1) % 7 == 0)subLine += "\n";
```

inside the loop in toString().

Comment: Ok, that does what i want it to do... seems so easy, and I make it so difficult.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not using `substring` here. This can be designed cleaner without it. Here is my 
suggestion which does not use `substring`. **This is mostly what you have, but I hope that in re-iterating the approach it can be seen that `substring` is not needed.**

To draw a calendar two things are needed: the start date and the days in the month (or the end date, which is the start date the days in the month).

Now, the process of drawing the calendar is simply the process of drawing the grid. Imagine each cell is identified with `(x, y)` such that the top-left is `(0,0)`, and `x` represents the day in the week (were Sunday is 0 and Saturday is 6).

1. Find the initial `(x, y)`. `y` will always be 0 (first row) but `x` will vary depending on the starting day of the week. For instance, `(2,0)` means the month started on Tuesday.
2. While not enough days have been placed, place another day in the cell `(x, y)` giving it the appropriate day-in-month value and advance `(x, y)` just as if going day 1, day 2, day 3... on a regular calendar.

Happy coding.